# Is there a way to change the imports on multiple Robot Framework files without manually opening each one?

Tags: robotframework

Basically one of the main import files changed directory so instead of the import file being ../../FileName it is now ../../../Filename. Is there a way to do this without opening each file and typing "../" every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your OS, IDE or other tool, just `Replace All`. Really easy with VSCode.

From CLI, you can try: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files

Answer (score 1):

Make a file system link - at the old location "../../FileName" pointing to the new one "../../../FileName".

Answer (score 0):

Use notepad ++ find and replace in files feature.
[image]